# How to chech Bosnian-specific characters in RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex, special-characters

I have this Regular Expression pattern, which is quite simple and it validates if the provided string is "alpha" (both uppercase and lowercase):

```
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/gi;
```

When I trigger `pattern.test('Zlatan Omerovic')` it returns `true`, however if I:

```
pattern.test('Zlatan Omerović');
```

It returns `false` and it fails my validation.

In Bosnian language we have these specific characters:

```
š đ č ć ž
```

And uppercased:

```
Š Đ Č Ć Ž
```

---

**Is it possible to validate these characters (both cases) with JavaScript regular expression?**

Comment: Yes, what have you tried? Protip: just add those between the square brackets.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - excatly that, what you see in the question :)

Comment: I meant, it looks like you just copypasta'd some regex that validates alphabetical characters but ok. If you look into the meaning of those square brackets - a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) - you'd know how to fix such regex.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: The character class `a-z` could well encompass `š` to a Bosnian. It doesn't in JavaScript, but that doesn't make it illogical from a non-English perspective.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I believe JS's character classes' ranges are ASCII code based, no? In that case a-z represents characters 97-122 (and 65-90 with the case-insensitive flag) only. Or these are UTF-8 based, not sure.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Yes, they are (well, not ASCII, but English). I'm just saying, to someone with a larger alphabet, it isn't necessarily obvious that `a-z` doesn't include their characters. Again, it *doesn't*, but that doesn't mean that's obvious. But look who I'm talking to! I guess you've been drinking the English Kool-Aid for a while, as I infer from the spelling of your name your native alphabet has a wider range than the English one. ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder heh true that. `=]` I just meant that `/[a-z]/i` is equivalent to `/[\u0061-\u007a]/i` (the ranges are UTF-8 based) and there's no accentuated characters in that range, just plain latin letters. `:P` And off-topic, I tend to use an algorithm that replaces non-latin letters by their latin-correspondent before doing string comparisons.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder But I understood what you meant, it is not obvious at first sight that accentuated characters don't belong in that range, it is just that I've been fighting these "odd" characters for quite a good while so I'm already used to the quirks necessary to account for non-latin characters and sometimes forget that it wasn't so easy at first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, you can just add those characters to the list of characters your matching. Also, since you're doing a case insensitive match (the `i` flag), you don't need the uppercase characters.

```
var pattern = /^[a-zšđčćž ]+$/gi;
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrill/KB74b/

Here's an alternate pattern, which uses the unicode representation, which might be better (embedding the characters won't work if the file isn't saved with the proper encoding, for instance)

```
var pattern = /^[a-z\u0161\u0111\u010D\u0107\u017E ]+$/gi;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrill/KB74b/2/

Comment: Missing the white space to match the example btw.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Ah, didn't see that. Fixed the regex

Answer (score 2):

`a-zA-Z` means exactly that, and in an English-centric way: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`. Sadly, with JavaScript's regular expressions, if you want to test other alphabetic characters, you have to specify them specifically. JavaScript doesn't have a locale-sensitive "alpha" definition. To include non-English alphabetic characters, you have to include them on purpose. You can either do that literally (for instance, by including `š` in the regular expression), or using Unicode escape sequences (such as `\u0161`). If the additional Bosnian alphabetic characters in question have a contiguous range, you can use the `-` notation with them as well, but it has to be separate from the `a-z`, which is defined in English terms.

Comment: I've seen a regex library that defines language-specific character ranges before, unfortunately I don't remember its name. Well, +1 as your answer is pretty well explained.

Answer (score 1):

To include in test result the first (S-based) symbol of your five I did:

```
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z\u0160-\u0161]+$/g;
```

Try to add all the symbols you need this way ;)

Comment: Although I'm pretty sure there is a bunch of full examples on Bosnian web sites ;)