# Regexp to test capital letters in Unicode

Tags: regex

I need regexp to test whether a string contains capital letters. I'm using the following regexp to do that `[\p{Lu}\p{Lt}]` but when tested using [this tool](http://regexpal.com/) with the phrase 'someCapitalLetters' it doesn't highlight capital letters but instead highlights letters 'p' and 't.

Comment: It would be clearer if you describe 'it doesn't seem to be working' more by means of examples and state the language/environment in which you're using the regex.

Comment: Do you need to match capitals from all languages, eg Arabic?

Comment: Not Arabic, but I need to match Russian language, so [A-Z] is not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be working fine. When tested against:

> Квуй фырре плььатонэм витюпэраторебуз йн, ед пырикульа рыпудяары
>   конкыптам шэа. Ат ыам ыёюз июварыт жямиляквюы, порро оптёон аккузата
>   нэ пэр. Алёэнюм аппэтырэ аккюжамюз эи ючю, нам ан лебыр квюандо. Ут
>   модо пробатуж праэчынт ыюм, ку векж брутэ элььэефэнд констятюам, пэр
>   ыт эрат витаэ доктюж.
>
> Жолюм оптёон пропрёаы вэл ад, ючю съюммо пондэрюм мандамюч эа, ты вим
>   кхоро мэльёуз пэрчыквюэрёж. Конгуы адипижкй зыд ан, ан эож ийжквюы
>   инимёкюж, экз квюот мюкиуж кюм. Ан квюот ёнвидюнт адолэжкэнс пэр.
>   Едквюэ альяквюам волуптариа эа ючю, вэл факэр модыратиюз йн, ыам
>   видишчы кончюлату вольуптатибюж ыт. Эю прё чэнзэрет аргюмынтум
>   эффякиантур. Адмодум коррюмпит ут квуй, ед шэа йужто пропрёаы.
>
> Минемум жплэндидэ ат квуй. Ад малйж анкилльаы компрэхэнжам эож, эним
>   номинави эи мыа. Мыа эю аюдиам факилиз окюррырэт. Унюм аргюмынтум
>   конкльюдатюрквюэ но хаж, мыа зальы натюм эи. Эжт йн льаорыыт омйттам
>   дёзсэнтёаш. Эю пэр граэки еракюндйа янтэрэсщэт, мюкиуж оффэндйт экз
>   кюм.

Matches are: `К` `А` `А` `У` `Ж` `К` `А` `Е` `Э` `А` `М` `А` `М` `У` `Э` `Э`

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/eE4qF6)

Note: I enabled the unicode modifier here.

Also, I forgot to mention that regexpal's regex is based on Javascript, which doesn't support the notation `\p{L}` (which is one more reason why you should mention what language you're using the regex in).

Comment: Thanks, I added `/u` modifier and it did the trick in PHP! I'm using the regexp in PHP and Javascript. You're saying that it won't work in JavaScript? How can the same be accomplished in JS?

Comment: @Maximus I don't know enough JS to answer that, but from what I can see, it might be difficult. I remember seeing a question where someone answered that using the unicodes (something like `\u32` or something...) was the way to go for special characters in JS. You might open a new question for that. [One possibly related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15981602/1578604). If you can find the unicode range of uppercase Russian characters, that should be doable and easy.

Answer (score 0):

I get similar results when using [:upper:] or [\p{Lu}] on a Java based reg-ex tester

http://regexpal.com/

Must be a limitation of the regex engine?

Try [A-Z] instead?